# Using a conda tool in my nextflow pipeline

Tags: bash, anaconda, bioinformatics, anaconda3, nextflow

I have a process to add in nextflow where I use a tool called medaka_haploid_variant.
I installed this tool using conda, and I have now an environment called second_part that contain this tool.

```
aziz@aziz-VirtualBox:~/pipeline$ medaka_haploid_variant
medaka_haploid_variant : commande introuvable

aziz@aziz-VirtualBox:~/pipeline$ conda activate second_part
aziz@aziz-VirtualBox:~/pipeline$ medaka_haploid_variant
medaka 1.8.0
```

As you see, the tool is well installed in that environment.
Anyway, I want now to use this tool in my nextflow script and what I usually do for that type of tools is to specifiy all the path to the script of interest:

```
script:
"""
/home/aziz/anaconda3/envs/second_part/bin/medaka_haploid_variant -i fastq -r reference -o output_folder
"""
```

This works perfectly for many other tools used in the same pipeline (Kraken2, samtools, minimap2, etc), but when it comes to medaka, I get this error:
Command error:

```
  /home/aziz/anaconda3/envs/second_part/bin/medaka_haploid_variant: ligne 12: medaka : commande introuvable
```

But when I activate the environment and then run the pipeline, the tool is perfectly working and I get my results.

I find this weird since this method works for all other tools.
I tried to look the nextflow documentation (conda part), but I didn't find something that helped me, so If you have any idea that can help me I will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to start a tool installed in a conda env (without activating it) is to do `conda run -n second_part medaka_haploid_variant` - does that change anything in your script?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message say that medaka is not found however you call medaka **_haploid_variant**. It means that the script medaka_haploid_variant exists but when it's arrive in line 12, it try to call medaka (installed in your venv) as see in the script -> https://github.com/nanoporetech/medaka/blob/master/scripts/medaka_haploid_variant

Answer (score 0):

You can specify existing environments in the `conda` directive too by simply putting the path to your environment. This way your process might look like this:

```
process medaka_haploid_variant {
    conda "/home/aziz/anaconda3/envs/second_part"
    input:
        tuple path(fastq), path(reference)
    output:
        path("output_folder")
    script:
    """
    medaka_haploid_variant -i fastq -r reference -o output_folder
    """
```

However, that script will only work with this pre-created environment. If you have only few dependencies in your environment it might be worth to just create environments on the fly - either by providing `environment.yml` files or directly conda packages (`conda "bioconda::medaka"`). Although to be honest this could potentially cause problems with medaka in case you can't install or download the required medaka-models because of connectivity issues on your machine (at runtime).